# Changing projection of Google Earth Engine code editor display

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine

I would like to change the projection on the code editor display window from EPSG:3857 (maps Mercator) to something else like Lambert conformal conic.

If this is not possible on code editor display window, what are my options to display Earth Engine images on a different projection?

I tried to look for tips on the projections documentation page but it can't find how to change the projection of the `Map` object in code editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.changeProj()` image method to change the projection of an image in the Map display. Note, however, that the Google Map tiles, Map scale bar, geometry tools, and the Inspector coordinates are still tied to the Map object's original canvas (EPSG:3857).

Here is an example from @Gennadii Donchyts (user:99557):

```js
var coords = ee.Image.pixelLonLat()
  .divide(10)
  .floor()
  .int()
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())
  .bitwiseAnd(1)
  .changeProj('EPSG:3031', 'EPSG:3857');

Map.addLayer(coords, {min:0, max:1});

var dem = ee.Image('NOAA/NGDC/ETOPO1').select('ice_surface')
  .changeProj('EPSG:3031', 'EPSG:3857');

Map.addLayer(
  dem.selfMask(),
  {min:-4000, max:4000,
  palette: ['1A2659','455285','7784B7','AAB7E8','D3E0FA','3C5600','7A711F','B79A5E','F1CEA4','FDFDE6']});

Map.setCenter(0, 0, 3);
```

[image]