# Setting projections for an earthengine app

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine

I am experimenting with [earthengine app](https://www.earthengine.app) as described at [Earth Engine Apps](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/apps).

I am trying to use a different projection than the default. This [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/348191/166347) to [Changing projection of Google Earth Engine code editor display](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348184) explains nicely how to change the projection of the maps, but the GoogleTiles remain in the default projection.

This [Custom Map Projections](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-projection-simple) tutorial explains how to change the projection of the background maps for Google Maps.

I was wondering if there was a way to to apply the tutorial of Google Maps to earthenegine apps